# Handling Bad URLs in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am working on ASP.NET MVC with Areas. I have three Areas. However, the default route is not an Area. When I ran the Application, I got this error:

[image: Areas_error]

The Routes are shown below:

RouteConfig

```
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
            namespaces: new string[] { "SmartSIMS.Web.Controllers" }
        );
    }
```

The Areas are:

1. Administration

   ```
       public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context) 
   {
       context.MapRoute(
           name: "Administration_default",
           url: "Administration/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
           defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
           namespaces: new string[] { "SmartSIMS.Web.Areas.Administration.Controllers" });
   }
   ```
2. Students

   ```
       public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context) 
   {
       context.MapRoute(
           name: "Students_default",
           url: "Students/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
           defaults: new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
           namespaces: new string[] { "SmartSIMS.Web.Areas.Students.Controllers" });
   }
   ```
3. Teachers

   ```
       public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context) 
   {
       context.MapRoute(
           name: "Teachers_default",
           url: "Teachers/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
           defaults: new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
           namespaces: new string[] { "SmartSIMS.Web.Areas.Teachers.Controllers" });
   }
   ```

How do I resolve this error? Kindly assist.

Comment: Where is the error? On the screenshot there is a diagnostic tool that tells you your default non-area route has successfully matched.

Comment: The issue is that, I don't want to display this. I want to display my Home page

Comment: Then disable whatever diagnostic tool that is. I've never seen it myself. By default there is a 404 error when no route in an MVC application matches.

Comment: I disabled diagnostic tool from Tools->Options. But the issue is still there

Comment: Problem resolved. I turned RouteDebugger in the web.config to false.  Thanks so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem resolved. I turned RouteDebugger in the web.config to false.